# Graphics drivers Problem

Tags: amd-graphics

I had Lenovo G510. It's graphics are from AMD. 
my Graphic card is AMD Radeon R200 series. Can anyone please provide me solution for my Graphic Drivers ?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve?

Comment: while watching any videos on browsers, the screen flashes continuously. what is the problem I don't understand.